# Group discount on top of tier price

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, tierprice, price-rules, rules

I have a customer group who gets 10% off on all products.

I have product with a tier price set.

Default Magento uses the highest "discount".

But that means my customer group in some cases gets the same discount as the regular visitors.

Is there any way to apply an extra discount on top of the tier price for my customer group?

Comment: if tier price give highest discount then as per as magento system it tier price will  apply..

Comment: Hi Amit, I know, but I would like to apply a discount on top of the tier price